# Is it bad to have a lot of AsyncTasks for simple database actions?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

There is a settings screen with multiple categories and each category has 5 to 6 its own settings. Just imagine settings screen of Android OS.

Now, to avoid having Set button on the bottom and trying to implement application of changes immediately upon a user changes any settings (thus to gain speed in the app and to have a better user experience), I thought of having dozens of `AsyncTask` classes, each implementing just a simple thing.

For example, there is a settings screen with 4 things to set. A user changes setting no.1 and I immediately call `AsyncTask` for that specific setting in the background. And like this for each change a user makes.

How smart is to do this? Would this overload `AsyncTask` idea or even come to the point that too many `AsyncTasks` are called consequently (I read that there is a limit of `AsyncTasks` that can be called, 5 or something)?

Is it a better design to call 1 `AsyncTask` with all changes when a user leave the specific settings screen?

Note: I am not asking here how to implement `AsyncTask`. My questions is directly bound to best design and the best speed of the app, as well the best UX.

Comment: Are your settings all saved to a server somewhere?  Surely many of them are stored locally.  Either way, you don't need dozens of AsyncTask implementations.  Just pass the AsyncTask your values that you're setting and create a generic AsyncTask to handle it.

Comment: Also, if you're saving changes in a separate thread, what if user makes a change and then quickly clicks on that same setting but it hasn't updated yet?  You can get concurrency issues unless you have something like a ProgressDialog there while AsyncTask is running.  In which case, you will never have more than one AsyncTask running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use asynctask when you have more than 1/2 operation(s) a minute or so (Quote in Android pushing the limits). You allocate a lot of objects and I peronally found that it looks like the Asynctasks are waiting on another. Maybe use a handler/runnable.

On a site note, you can save all the changes in variables in memory and then periodically save the settings to a backing store. There is nothing faster than just setting an instance variable/array.